# Why did a moderator delete my post?

Tags: discussion

I posted my opinion that it might be harder to produce a straight than it is to produce a flush. A moderator deleted my post!!   I'd like to understand why my post was deleted ?? that is sensorship at its worst.

Comment: Hi Josh, I just checked for you, and it was deleted as they did not want to cause confusion to other users due to the error in the answer.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in Poker Meta?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in meta.

Comment: For a starter, please take a [tour] to grasp how this site (and SE sites in general) works.

Answer (score 3):

Josh
Since we don't have your "post" I am not sure if you made a post or replied to a post. Just to clarify, at SE sites we ask questions and give answers. We don't "post" in the regular sense like on a forum or comments section of a web page. We don't really do a dialogue.

So it may be you posted just an opinion about straight being harder to make then a flush. Which is not a question, and perhaps not an answer, therefore rightly deleted by a moderator. (I have not seen were you posted). You can post your own question, then answer it. by posting a question like which is tougher to make a straight or a flush? (BTW most poker players with experience already know that it is harder to make a straight draw with 8 outs vs 9 outs for a flush draw and at some point wonder why therefore a straight does not beat a flush.) Before you do post, look around a little bit you might find the question has already been asked and answered.

[I can safely say that question has already been posted.](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6213/up-down-straight-draw-vs-flush-draw-comparison?s=7|0.6083) please check that answer you will be surprised what you learn.

If you were answering a question:
There are many reasons a Moderator would close an answer to a post. Low quality answer, that is not an answer but an opinion, or is poorly written, or adds nothing other then rehash previous answers or has nothing to do with the question.